# How to remove unwanted empty item present at first index for a select list in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two different select list each one fill with an empty item at first index after view created.

```
`<h3>Select Age:</h3>
   <div class="list">
     <label class="item item-input item-select">
       <div class="input-label">From</div>
       <select ng-model="ageFrom" 
         ng-name="page"
         ng-options="age for age in Range(18, 75)" 
         data-tap-disabled="true"
         ng-change="onAgeFromSelected(ageFrom)">
       </select>
       {{ageFrom}}
     </label>
     <label class="item item-input item-select">
       <div class="input-label">To</div>
       <select 
         ng-model="ageTo" 
         ng-name="page" 
         ng-options="age for age in Range( ageToStartIndex, 75)" 
         data-tap-disabled="true">
       </select>
       {{ageTo}}
     </label>
   </div>`
```

Here's [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mablevj/LrzsemLc/1/) for complete implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want are the following:

1. Enable start values for both from and to select boxes (currently showing blank)
2. Upon selecting From, the start index of to should be the value selected in From.

I am not clear when you say "Preselection is also not working due to" *the particular issue* (do you mean preselection for second dropdown upon choosing first or the preselection of each one of them upon initial page load?)

I think you are trying to do dependent dropdowns whose value you are not able to fix *upon change*

Even then I am not sure if you would need the extra variable for startIndex, may be.

Then

> this JS should do:

```
        var app=angular.module('App', []);
        function ctrl($scope){

            $scope.ageFrom = 18;
            $scope.ageTo = 18;

            $scope.ageToStartIndex = 18;

            $scope.onAgeFromSelected = function (value) {
            $scope.ageToStartIndex = value;
              $scope.ageTo = value;
            }

            $scope.Range = function (start, end) {
              var result = [];
              for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            result.push(i);
              }
              return result;
            };
        }
```

> HTML remains the same.

[Check the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/newjavaonemahesh/c5cmramd/).

Comment: Preselection means:- Initially both list have value **18**. But as per my implementation both are showing blank. The second list range must be start based on the value present in first list.

Comment: [Check my fiddle now](https://jsfiddle.net/newjavaonemahesh/c5cmramd/) - I think I never set it as base, was actually still pointing to your version.
It does the following:  
1.  On page load, sets to 18 (both dropdown).
2.  When you chose, say 20, that becomes the start of range for second dropdown.
3.  Second dropdown now becomes 20.  Selecting anything in the second dropdown does not affect the first.
4.  If you again change the first dropdown value, the second changes as above with selected value as whatever you selected in the first.

Answer (score 1):

Add Following Code :

```
 <option style="display:none" value="">select a type</option>
```

Full Code Like :

```
<div ng-app="App" >
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<h3>Select Age:</h3>
<div class="list">
 <label class="item item-input item-select">
   <div class="input-label">From</div>
   <select ng-model="ageFrom" 
     ng-name="page"
     ng-options="age for age in Range(18, 75)" 
     data-tap-disabled="true"
     ng-change="onAgeFromSelected(ageFrom)">         
      <option style="display:none" value="">select a type</option>
   </select>
   {{ageFrom}}
   </label>
   <label class="item item-input item-select">
   <div class="input-label">To</div>
   <select 
     ng-model="ageTo" 
     ng-name="page" 
     ng-options="age for age in Range( ageToStartIndex, 75)" 
     data-tap-disabled="true">
       <option style="display:none" value="">select a type</option>
   </select>
   {{ageTo}}
   </label>
   </div>
   </div>       
   </div>
```

Comment: Can i use the exact value instead of _selecte type_. So that initially both list will have value with range start from 18 and if `onAgeFromSelected()` for list 1 is invoked, the second list will also updated the range based on the `onAgeFromSelected()` value.